# Pass event object to trigger function in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom-events

This is the MCVE of the problem I'm having. Let say I have this very simple test page:

```
<html>
<header>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function testMethod(e){
            alert(e.target.id);
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn_test").on("click", testMethod, event);           
        });
    </script>
</header>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn_test" value="OK" />
</body>
</html>
```

You can find the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gwweevms/).

In Chrome or IE, when I push the button, the id will be displayed in a message box. But in Firefox since window.event is not defined, I cannot bind testMethod to the button's onclick event.

I know that if I'm writting it inline, I can pass the event like this:

```
onclick="testMethod(event)"
```

But how can I pass event to my function in Firefox without writing it inline?

Comment: There is no reason to have `, event)`. That's already passed into the `testMethod` since it's bound to a click event handler.

Comment: `event` is a non-standard global variable that was introduced in IE, and copied by Chrome and Safari. But Firefox doesn't have it. It's not needed because the event is passed as an argument to the event listener.

Comment: I see, I feel stupid now. Since it is not need, no wonder I can't find how to pass the event to method no matter how I search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when you subscribe to an event using `on` or `addEventListener`, the event object is passed as a parameter to a callback. You never have to pass it explicitly when you register your callback. So this will do:

```
$("#btn_test").on("click", testMethod);
```

The problem with your code on Firefox is that there is no global `event` property and you get an error:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
```

and your event subscription never gets registered.

Answer (score 1):

remove the the 3rd parameter it works on firefox.

```
$("#btn_test").on("click", testMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the jQuery Reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler), you'll notice that the third parameter has to be the handler. So, simply remove the third parameter and pass the handler to achieve this.

Check out the demo fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbsatter/6j84rpos/).

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn_test" value="OK" />
</body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function testMethod(e){
            alert(e.target.id);
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn_test").on("click", testMethod);           
        });
    </script>
```